# How to replace query values with my own in the @GET URI?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

According to retrofit:

> You can also specify query parameters in the URL.
>
> @GET("users/list?sort=desc")

How can I replace 'desc' with my own parameter?

Do I have to structure my URI to have the `?variable=`. Or I just use the @Query() annotation? I am having a failed response, I cannot single out server, or my URI. So I don't know where I am getting this. Here is what I am doing:

```
        Call<List<People>> peopleRankingRequest =
                peopleService.getAllPeopleRanking(
                        apiKey
                        , past28Days.getTimeInMillis() / 1000
                        , now.getTimeInMillis() / 1000
                        , "00:00"
                        , "00:00"
                        , ""
                        , "");
```

Here is my service interface:

```
public interface PeopleService
{
    @GET("franchisee/ranking/people/")
    Call<List<People>> getAllPeopleRanking(
            @Header("X-API-KEY") String apiKey
            , @Query("period_start") long periodStart
            , @Query("period_end") long periodEnd
            , @Query("time_start") String timeStart
            , @Query("time_end") String timeEnd
            , @Query("site_id") String siteIDs
            , @Query("type_id") String typeIDs);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another query parameter like this

```
public interface PeopleService
{
@GET("franchisee/ranking/people/")
Call<List<People>> getAllPeopleRanking(
        @Header("X-API-KEY") String apiKey
        , @Query("period_start") long periodStart
        , @Query("period_end") long periodEnd
        , @Query("time_start") String timeStart
        , @Query("time_end") String timeEnd
        , @Query("site_id") String siteIDs
        , @Query("type_id") String typeIDs
        , @Query("sort") String sortValue
         );
}
```

Comment: although your answer similar to the one in my post, I realized it works even though you did not specify the query in URI/URL. Thanks! I thought I am having the error on my end, when it was actually the server's.